# Regex pattern to match number and only one string

Tags: regex, angular, regex-group

I am new to regex and I want to validate create a validator pattern for number and only one string (M|m|T|t|B|b).

Here is the one I have tried `/^\d*|(M|m|T|t|B|b){1}`

But I am not able to create it. These are the test criteria I want to pass

```
1234b > pass
1234B > pass
.124b > pass
0.123 > pass
1234bb > fail
12345e > fail
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:\d*\.\d+|\d+)[MTBmtb]{0,1}\b
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6E0WHQ/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\d*\.\d+` - matches 0+ digits followed by a decimal followed by 1+ occurrences of a digit
- `|` - OR
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits
- `[MTBmtb]{0,1}` - matches 0 or 1 occurrence of either of the the letters - `M`, `T`, `B`, `m`, `t`, `b`
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: I think this is actually what the OP is looking for, although he didn't make himself clear. One thing though, `{0,1}` can be replaced with `?`.

Comment: Yes. It can be replaced by `?`

Comment: I am looking for input field validation which accepts number and aberration ie user can put 1m (1million)

Comment: Yes. The provided regex matches `1m` too. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/6E0WHQ/3)